# AWS RDSへの接続でエラーが発生

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

AWS上のDBに接続できず困っています。

RDSインスタンスを作成し、MySQL Workbenchで

- ホスト名
- ポート番号
- ユーザ名
- パスワード

を入力して接続を試みたのですが、以下のようなエラーが出て接続に失敗します。

```
Cannot Connection to Database Server
your connection attempt failed for user '○○○○' to the MySQL server at ...
```

セキュリティグループもインバウンドの3306からの通信は開放済みです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

パブリックアクセシビリティも**あり**にしています。

コマンドライン上で接続を試みた場合、以下のようなエラーとなり接続に失敗します。

```
> mysql -h ○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u ○○○○ -p
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '○○○○'@'○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○○' (using password: YES)
```

使用OSとMySqlのバージョンは以下の通りです。

```
> mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

> cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
```

Comment: mysqlのユーザのhostは何を設定しましたか？'%'ワイルドカードを設定しても繋がらないですか？

Comment: hostには何も設定していません。
以下のコマンドでmysqlのインストールを行ってから、mysqlに関する設定は何も行っていない状態です。
`sudo apt install mysql-client-core-5.7`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

インスタンス設定時に自動生成されたパスワードが正常に登録されていないことが原因のようでした。
パスワードを再設定すると接続が成功するようになりました。